# Does using nodejs reverse proxy helps in terms of bandwidth

Tags: node.js, reverse-proxy

I'm wondering if using nodejs reverse proxy has any effects in terms of bandwidth or not, for example you have two servers `server 1 --> mainWebsite.com`  and `server 2 --> videosWebsite.com` who's responsible for serving videos. so when i do this:

```
app.all("/videos/:id/",  function(req, res) {
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: 'videosWebsite.com'});
});
```

Does `mainWebsite.com` download the video from `videosWebsite.com` then send it to the client ( meaning consummation of bandwidth in both servers ) or the consummation is just on the `videosWebsite.com` ( when i say bandwidth i mean the bandwidth needed to serve the video ).
My question is very simple but i don't know how to explain it , maybe the following example will make it clear.
Every single video is 1 Gb, when we request it 100 times through reverse proxy, that makes `videosWebsite.com` upload 100 Gb of bandwidth to the client, my question is: what about the server that made the reverse proxy or who contain it, does he download that 100Gb from `videosWebsite.com` than send it to the client (upload 100Gb to the client) or not ?

Comment: Which exact npm module are you using for your proxy functionality?  Can you provide a link?

Comment: @jfriend00 i'm using this npm module : [node-http-proxy]( https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does mainWebsite.com download the video from videosWebsite.com then send it to the client

Yes, when you implement a proxy the way you're showing, you end up using double the bandwidth.  When the client requests a video that video is downloaded from the target server to your server and then send from your server to the client.

> Every single video is 1 Gb, when we request it 100 times through reverse proxy, that makes videosWebsite.com upload 100 Gb of bandwidth to the client, my question is: what about the server that made the reverse proxy or who contain it, does he download that 100Gb from videosWebsite.com than send it to the client (upload 100Gb to the client) or not ?

From your server's point of view, you would use 100GB of download bandwidth (retrieving the video from the target server to your server) and 100GB of upload bandwidth (sending it from your server to the client).

---

The only way to avoid this doubling of bandwidth is to have the client download the video directly from the target and not go through your proxy.  If these resources are static and do not change, you could also implement caching on your own server and avoid the double bandwidth on any resource that's in the cache.

Comment: i'm doing all this to avoid consuming bandwidth from the main server, i read about the reverse proxy that it can be used us load balancer , if it's like what you said ( doubling the bandwidth ) then how can it be used as a load balancer, i mean the purpose of using load balancer is to share the bandwidth needed between several servers not to double it :)

Comment: @ler - You'd have to show your overall network layout to understand what you have configured so far and what you're trying to do.  I don't understand your objective or where various servers are located.  Local bandwidth on your local LAN between your own two servers is probably fast and nearly free so that's fine.  But bandwidth in and out of your hosting facility costs $$.  I don't understand your overall layout or your objective.

Comment: what i'm trying to achieve is to avoid consuming bandwidth from my main server meaning serving the video from a specific server + use my main website link ( because i want to add some parameter to the link, and i don't want to expose those params ), i'm using this nodejs module   [node-http-proxy]( github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) , i don't know if that's possible or not.

Comment: for example my website link  `website.com/video/1.mp4` my app receive this link and add some params like this `videoWebsite.com/video/1.mp4/param1/param2` then send the result to the client, i don't want the client to know about `param1` and `param2` , and also i don't want to consume the bandwidth from my main server. i don't know if that possible or not

Comment: @ler - Assuming the server videoWebsite.com is outside your local LAN where your website.com server is, you can't do that without consuming extra hosting bandwidth.  You could "redirect" the client to `http://videoWebsite.com/video/1.mp4/param1/param2` and have the client go fetch it directly and thus not consume extra bandwidth, but then the client could know about param1/param2.  Proxying an external site takes more bandwidth.

Comment: ok i see thanks for the information, but why they said that you can use reverse proxy as load balancer ? i read that in almost every article about reverse proxy

Comment: It would be used as a load balancer to spread the load across a couple of local hosts on the same LAN where the bandwidth is local, fast and free.  So, there's be 1x bandwidth from the hosting center and then a extra bandwidth within the local LAN which doesn't cost you anything and is very fast (probably 1Gbps).  You would not  typically use it to load balance across two remote hosts because that would cost extra.